# Select name from record that has highest value or else second-highest value

Tags: sql, db2

I want to select name from table where Ranking is 'First'.
And if there is no record where Ranking = 'First' then take name where Ranking is 'Second'.

Examples:

```
--------------------
ID F_NAME  RANKING
--------------------
1  Tom     Second
2  John    Third
3  Sarah   First
--------------------
```

Expected output: Sarah

```
ID F_NAME  RANKING
--------------------
1  Tom     Second
2  John    Third
3  James   Fourth
--------------------
```

Expected output: Tom

Only First or Second should be displayed. Others like Third, Fourth doesn't matter.

This query is for DB2. How can I write such query?

Comment: Have you made a start on this query? What problem are you having specifically?

Comment: You literally have the words `first` `second` `third` `fourth` and so on?

Comment: If you're creating this table, use integers for rankings and order by instead. Otherwise there's a decent answer below.  You could also reorder it in code, but that doesn't sit right with me, haha.

Comment: You have misunderstood the function of *Stack Overflow*: we are here to help one another with apparently intractable programming issues. You must supply your code, realistic input data, the corresponding expected result, and detail of the errors and unwanted behaviour for us to be able to say anything useful at all. Occasionally you will find that low-level subscribers thirsty for reputation will write a solution for you from scratch, but that is a misuse of the system. I have voted to close your question on the grounds that it is *too broad*.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ORDER BY` and [`FETCH FIRST`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_fetchfirstclause.html):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE Ranking IN ('First', 'Second')
ORDER BY Ranking
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=52a1c6ad704ec63db16e0e00d252b9e9)**

Comment: I believe this will order by string values - so, "First" would come before "Second", but "Fourth" would come second with First, Second, Third, Fourth.  They would be ordered First, Fourth, Second, Third.

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but your Fiddle is for PostgreSQL, and the OP is using DB2.

Comment: @halfer DB2 supports FETCH FIRST, added link to docs. There is no DB2 playground so I have to use alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number` with a conditional expression in `order by`.

```
select *
from (select t.*,row_number() over(order by case when ranking='First' then 1
                                                 when ranking='Second' then 2
                                                --add more rankings as needed
                                            else 3 end) as rnum 
      from tbl t
     ) t
where rnum=1
```

Comment: To explain further, downvotes on unresearched questions are added in order to discourage answers being given to lazy questions, in order ultimately to discourage lazy questions. There is a view that some folks - even high-rep members - don't mind attracting lazy questions, even to the detriment of Stack Overflow. Whether good answers to bad questions are done for helpfulness or for increasing already high personal rep counts is a matter of ongoing disagreement (for what it's worth, I upvoted this, despite my misgivings).

Comment: See Borodin's comment under the question also.